# mwlDraggable (Drag & Drop) - minimum length of move

Tags: html, angular

I have a problem with mat-card, that is draggable and also contains some button. Unfortunately, on my PC button (click) don't work at all, on my collegue it works sometimes. We think that it can be caused as click is treated as dragging element. Is there anyway to set minimal length of move (dragging), which causes starting treating object as moved?

It was tested on 2 machines - the same code, different behaviour - one one (click) on button is never executed, on second one - sometimes.

What I found now on my computer - while I'm debugging it (Chrome) - when I move my mouse cursor over cards on one of cases occurring this - I get blue "shadow" over the whole app from debugger, but button is clickable - it works as I expected, otherwise - not.

```
<mat-card mwlDraggable *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [dragActiveClass]="'field-dragged'"
[dropData]="item" (dragEnd)="itemFieldDragEnd($event, item)">
<mat-card-content>
   <div class="pull-left m-t-5">
      {{item.name}}
      <div class="field-meta truncate">
         {{item.desc}}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pull-right">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="onItemFieldClick($event, item)" matTooltip="somehint">
         <mat-icon class="md-24">arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
      </button>
   </div>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

I want to obtain way to force mwlDraggable to become draggable only if it was moved really by let's say 10px, not before. Or any other solution that would work for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on github: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-draggable-droppable/issues/53

Exemplary fully implemented solution using above:

```
<mat-card mwlDraggable *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [dragActiveClass]="'field-dragged'"
[dropData]="item" (dragEnd)="itemFieldDragEnd($event, item)"
[validateDrag]="dragThresholdValidator">
<mat-card-content>
   <div class="pull-left m-t-5">
      {{item.name}}
      <div class="field-meta truncate">
         {{item.desc}}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pull-right">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="onItemFieldClick($event, item)" matTooltip="somehint">
         <mat-icon class="md-24">arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
      </button>
   </div>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

```
public dragThresholdValidator({ x, y }: any): boolean {
    const min_drag_threshold = 5;
    return Math.abs(x) > min_drag_threshold || Math.abs(y) > min_drag_threshold;
}
```